# sort dictionaries in array by value of certain key

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift, dictionary

I am trying to create a function which will sort my array:

[Online demo here](http://swiftstub.com/885398013/)

```
let dictArr = [     ["name": "asd", "sell": 0.258, "buy": "5.52"],
                    ["name": "dbs", "sell": 1.258, "buy": "4.52"],
                    ["name": "fdd", "sell": 2.258, "buy": "3.52"]]
```

Lets say I would like to sort dictionaries inside my dictArr by "sell" key.

What I was tried is:

```
dictArr.sort {
    item1, item2 in
    let val1 = item1["sell"] as Double
    let val2 = item2["sell"] as Double
    return val1 > val2
}
```

This is not working. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.sort is a mutating function. When mutating an array you cant make it a let. You have to just change let to var and you're good to go.

Just take a look at the error message you get next time ;)

Comment: indeed! I am new in swift :) thanks! everything works

Comment: Or maybe used Array.sorted which return a new array so you don't mutate the original array.